# Why is Bitmap Scan0 still valid after unlocking?

Tags: c#, pointers, bitmap

As far as I know, there is no concept of pointer in managed environment where garbage collector is in charge of memory management. Like if someone wants to manipulate the pixel values in a bitmap, she/he has to first lock it like the following code does.

```
Bitmap Image = new Bitmap(width, height, 
                   System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
BitmapData bmpData = Image.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, 
PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
IntPtr imageScan0 = bmpData.Scan0;
unsafe
{
    byte* ptr = (byte*)imageScan0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            *ptr++ = 128;
        }
            }
        }
Image.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

My main problem is that:
If I store the imageScan0 information and then unlock the bitmap, I can still use the imageScan0 to manipulate its values just like I manipulate it between lock and unlock operations.

I have tested it and I am surprised to see that imageScan0 is still valid to manipulate.
My guess is that the underlying bitmap resides on unmanaged memory.

Comment: Of course it is possible to manipulate after UnlockBits, but it is not guaranteed. It may or may not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My main problem is that: If I store the imageScan0 information and then unlock the bitmap, I can still use the imageScan0 to manipulate its values just like I manipulate it between lock and unlock operations.

You can. But that does not mean you *may*.

The system just isn't designed to immediately invalidate the memory 100% of the time when you unlock it. The lock gave you a pointer, and promised that for the duration until you unlock, that pointer will remain valid.

But the converse isn't true. The system doesn't guarantee the pointer will immediately become *invalid* after you unlock.

But that also doesn't mean you can go around using it. You've told the system you're done with the pointer. It's now free to move it, invalidate it, whatever it wants at any time. You're playing with fire if you continue to use it.

It is not a problem per se for the pointer to remain valid after being unlocked. It *is* a problem for you to use it; it's *your* job to make sure you don't, not the system's.